# Can I numerically solve these equations in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration, complex, tensors, differential-geometry

I have this couple of equations :

$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu z^i + G^{i\bar{p}} (\partial_j G_{k\bar{p}} ) \partial_\mu z^j \partial^\mu z^k + G^{i\bar{j}} (\partial_{\bar{j}} G_{k\bar{l}} ) \partial_\mu z^k \partial^\mu z^{\bar{l}} =0
$

and

$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu z^{\bar{i}} + G^{p\bar{i}} (\partial_{\bar{j}} G_{\bar{k} p} ) \partial_\mu z^{\bar{j}} \partial^\mu z^{\bar{k}} + G^{\bar{i}j} (\partial_j G_{k\bar{l}} ) \partial_\mu z^k \partial^\mu z^{\bar{l}} =0
$

They are the equations of motion of $z$ (scalar field) and its complex conjugate on complex coordinates. $\mu=0,1,2,3$ (Lorentz index) , and $i,j,...= 1,2, ...,$ to any arbitrary values

Can I solve these equations in Mathematica to get $z^i$ and the matrix $G_{ij}$, even numerically?

Edit:

Note: Again these are E.O.M of $z$ field on complex coordinates so that $G_{ij}$ is the metric on these coordinates (complex space of a manifold).

Take the equations in the direction: $i,j,...=1$, any glimpse for a solution in two unknown variables?

$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu z^1 + G^{11^*} (\partial_1 G_{11^*} ) \partial_\mu z^1 \partial^\mu z^1 + G^{11^*} (\partial_{1^*} G_{11^*} ) \partial_\mu z^1 \partial^\mu z^{1^*} =0$

and

$ \partial_\mu \partial^\mu z^{1^*} + G^{11^*} (\partial_{1^*} G_{1^* 1} ) \partial_\mu z^{1^*} \partial^\mu z^{1^*} + G^{1^*1} (\partial_1 G_{11^*} ) \partial_\mu z^1 \partial^\mu z^{1^*} =0
$

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Mathematica cannot directly solve PDEs on $\mathbb{C}^n$;  you'd have to recast the equations as PDEs on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ instead.

Comment: @S.S. If you  define G, then we can find a solution to a certain class of problems. In principle, this is not very different from the Yang-Mills theory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98870/discussion-on-question-by-s-s-can-i-numerically-solve-these-equation-in-mathema).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Mathematica can't analyse this type of equation "out of the box."  Its built-in numerical PDE solvers are limited to solving boundary-value and initial-value problems on real manifolds, not complex manifolds (though the functions you're solving for can, I believe, be complex.)

It also doesn't automatically know how to expand quantities like $\partial_\mu \partial^\mu$;  you'd have to explicitly provide it with all 16 terms<sup>1</sup> of the summation.  It does know about the Laplacian operator—check out `Laplacian` in the documentation–so that's a small mercy if you're working on a manifold with a lot of symmetry like Minkowski or de Sitter spacetimes.

I would recommend looking into the [xAct suite](http://www.xact.es), particularly the `xCoba` and `xTras` packages.  In particular, this suite allows you to use tensor indices on various bundles, including (I believe) complex bundles on real manifolds, which is what you appear to have here.  In principle, `xCoba` can reduce these equations to a set of real-valued functions on a real manifold if you provide it with an ansatz to work with;  and you can then (in principle) try feed these equations into `NDSolve`.  I will warn you that the learning curve for `xAct` is a bit steep; but if you're going to be doing these calculations frequently, it's worth learning.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or, if this is a string theory problem (which it has the air of), 100 terms.

Comment: I think I can write something like $\partial_\mu f$, is it `D[f[t,x,y,z],{{t,x,y,z}}]`  ? , but also till here can Mathematica vary between $\partial_\mu f$ and $\partial^\mu f$ ? , I mean how to write then $ \partial ^\mu f$ ?

Comment: @S.S.:  You'd have to write that as something like $g^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu f$, which you could do in principle by defining $g^{\mu \nu}$ as a matrix and then using `Dot` to perform the contraction with $\partial_\nu f$.  But going this route is dangerous, as it is **extremely** easy to get confused about which indices are covariant and which are contravariant;  Mathematica does not have any built-in way of keeping track of this.  The `xAct` package is much, much better in this regard, which is why I recommended it.

Comment: Yes of course I will try it and the other packages which you mentioned in your answer, but I’m trying now to solve my equations  roughly :  if i have a term like $\partial_\mu f \partial^\mu f $ , without any package how can I write it?

Comment: may be I wasn’t clear enough in my previous  comment  ; I mean if have $\partial_\nu f$ alone I have to multiply by $g^{\mu\nu}$, but if there is a complete term $\partial_\mu f \partial^\mu f$ we don’t have to multiply by the metric. But will it written in Mathematica just by: `D[f[t,x,y,z], {{t,x,y,z}}] * D[f[t,x,y,z], {{t,x,y,z}}]`. Can’t we take the Conjugate of D as $\partial^\mu$ ?

Comment: @S.S.  No.  There's no functionality in basic Mathematica to raise & lower indices;  you have to write out all the metrics explicitly, unless the metric is the flat Euclidean metric (in which case the difference between raised & lowered indices is immaterial.)  And the quantity $(\partial \mu  f)( \partial^\mu f)$ is shorthand for $g^{\mu \nu} (\partial \mu f) (\partial \nu f)$;  the metric is inherently in there.

Comment: Oh, I know the metric is there!! But I’m not sure it’s flat or no.

Comment: Hi, Can you see the equations after I wrote them now in most simple way , I mean with no complex and flat g . If they are right, has you an idea how to solve them then by Solve or NDSolve. They are in a new question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206598/solving-pd-equations-with-4d-laplacian-and-derivatives

Comment: And I cannot tag you Michael Seifert, don’t no why.